# adding multiple AddListener in polygons google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon, geojson

I have added on a google map some polygons and multipolygons from geojson data.
My need is to print out the name of the countries in an infowindow when the event "mousemove" is in the polygon. I have also set a legend and i want to reload it when the event "dblclick" is on the polygon.

Here's my problem: I can't do the "mousemove" and the "dblclick" event for all the polygons and multipolygons, it just take the last one polygon and multipolygon casted by my function.

Here's my full code (UPDATE):

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    });
    var countries = ['Germany','France','Moldova','Italy','Spain'];
    var infoWindow = document.createElement('div');
         infoWindow.id = 'infoWindow';
         var content1 = [];
         content1.push('<h3>Default </h3>');

         infoWindow.innerHTML = content1.join('');
         infoWindow.index = 2;
         map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(infoWindow);

   var state = new google.maps.Data();
   var poly ;
   var polys = new Array();


   var gaArr = new Array();
   var p = 0;
   var mp = 0;

//the problem is here
   state.addListener('addfeature',function(evt) {
//my 5 objects pass here
    var CouName = evt.feature.getProperty('name');
     if (evt.feature.getProperty('type') == 'Polygon') {
      var ga = state.getFeatureById(CouName);
      var gaGeom = ga.getGeometry();
      gaArr = gaGeom.getAt(0).getArray();
      poly = new google.maps.Polygon({paths:gaArr, map:map,clickable:false,visible:false});
       google.maps.event.addListener(map,'dblclick',function(evt){
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(evt.latLng, poly)) {
        legend.innerHTML =  CouName;
        }
      });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'mousemove',function(evt){
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(evt.latLng, poly)) {
        infoWindow.innerHTML = CouName;
        }
    });
    p++;

     }

      if (evt.feature.getProperty('type') == 'MultiPolygon') {
       var ga = state.getFeatureById(CouName);
       var gaGeom = ga.getGeometry();
       gaArr = gaGeom.getArray();
       for (var i=0;i<gaGeom.getArray().length;i++){
        polys[i]= new google.maps.Polygon({paths:gaArr[i].getAt(0).getArray(), map:map,clickable:false,visible:false});
       }

       google.maps.event.addListener(map,'dblclick',function(evt){
    for(var i=0;i<gaArr.length;i++){
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(evt.latLng, polys[i])) {
        legend.innerHTML = CouName;
        }
      }
      });

   google.maps.event.addListener(map,'mousemove',function(evt){
    for(var i=0;i<gaArr.length;i++){
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(evt.latLng, polys[i])) {
        infoWindow.innerHTML = CouName;
        }
      }
      });
   mp++;
   }
    });
    for (var country in countries){
             state.loadGeoJson('http://.../GoogleMaps/'+countries[country]+'.geojson', {
             idPropertyName: 'name'

             });

    }
   state.setMap(map);
   //to color the polygons
   state.setStyle(function(feature) {

            var k = feature.getProperty('color');
            return {
                fillOpacity:0.6,
                fillColor:k,
                strokeWeight:1,
                clickable: false
            }
        });
```

I Think the problem is the Polygon array polys and the polygon poly are deleted when state.addListener pass to another polygon or multipolygon, and as i said, the addlistener works for the last ones polygon and multipolygon casted by the function.

I don't know if it can help but below is an example of my geojson files:

```
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"color":"purple","name":"Germany","type":
 "MultiPolygon"},"geometry":{"type": "MultiPolygon","coordinates":
[[[[8.5636100769042969,54.684165954589844],
[8.5948600769042969,54.719856262207031],[8.5851364135742187,54.7445068359375],
[8.5511093139648437,54.753883361816406],[8.4447212219238281,54.74832...]]]]}}


{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name": "Moldova","color":"green","type": 
"Polygon"},"geometry":{"type": "Polygon","coordinates":
[[[28.108325958251953,46.102291107177734],[28.0...]]]]}}
```

I thought about looping on all multipolygons and polygons and making an array of polygons and an array of array of polygons but it didn't work.

Comment: There is no `map` created by your "full" code.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Ok, I updated my code, i forgot the map creation.. I didn't put the css for the legend and the script for the google map key too. I haven't been enough clear about my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I update below state.addListener:

```
state.addListener('addfeature',function(evt) {

    var CouName = evt.feature.getProperty('name');
     if (evt.feature.getProperty('type') == 'Polygon') {
      var c = p;
      var ga = state.getFeatureById(CouName);
      var gaGeom = ga.getGeometry();
      gaArr = gaGeom.getAt(0).getArray();
      //here I push all my polygons in my array poly
      poly.push(new google.maps.Polygon({paths:gaArr, map:map,clickable:false,visible:false}));
       google.maps.event.addListener(poly[c],'dblclick',function(evt){
        alert(poly.length);
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(evt.latLng, poly[c])) {
        legend.innerHTML =  CouName;
        }
      });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'mousemove',function(evt){
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(evt.latLng, poly[c])) {
        infoWindow.innerHTML = CouName;
        }
    });
    p++;

     }

      if (evt.feature.getProperty('type') == 'MultiPolygon') {

       var cp= mp;


       var ga = state.getFeatureById(CouName);
       var gaGeom = ga.getGeometry();
       gaArr = gaGeom.getArray();

       for (var i=0;i<gaGeom.getArray().length;i++){
        //here I push all my polygons of my multipolygons in my array polys
        polys.push(new google.maps.Polygon({paths:gaArr[i].getAt(0).getArray(), map:map,clickable:false,visible:false}));
       }

       google.maps.event.addListener(map,'dblclick',function(evt){

    for(var i=cp;i<cp+gaGeom.getArray().length;i++){

      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(evt.latLng, polys[i])) {
        legend.innerHTML = CouName;
        }
      }
      });

   google.maps.event.addListener(map,'mousemove',function(evt){
    for (var i=cp;i<cp+gaGeom.getArray().length;i++){
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(evt.latLng, polys[i])) {
        infoWindow.innerHTML = CouName;
        }
      }
      });
   mp=mp+gaGeom.getArray().length;
    }
   });
```